# Where to Properly Place the While-Do Statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I just started programming not too long ago and I am really interested in learning more. Right now, I am in the middle of creating a small "if-else", "while-do" scenario where the user will respond to the questions with the correct integers. I am having trouble though and whenever I hit this part of code:

```
if (chopperCrash > 100) {   


        System.out.println("That's not possible!");

        System.out.println("Hurry and re-enter a new value before we crash!");
        continue;
```

It continually loops the printed text. Can someone help me on this specific project and also explain to me in detail proper placement of "if-else" and "while-do" statements? Thank you for any help. My apologies if this has already been answered and I am too dense to understand the other previously asked questions. Here is my full block of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstClass {
public static void main (String[] args){

    System.out.println("The chopper is going down because your lack of experience.");

    System.out.println("How much throttle are you going to give it?");

    System.out.println("(enter a number between 1 and 100)");

    Scanner FirstScan = new Scanner(System.in);


    int number = FirstScan.nextInt();
    int chopperCrash = number;

    while (true){       

    if (chopperCrash >= 60 && chopperCrash <= 100){

        System.out.println("Looks like we'll make it another day!");
        break;
    }

        else{       

    if (chopperCrash > 100) {   


        System.out.println("That's not possible!");

        System.out.println("Hurry and re-enter a new value before we crash!");
        continue;
    }
    else{
    if (chopperCrash <= 59) {
        System.out.println("Not enough throttle!");
        System.out.println("We're going down!");

        break;
             }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left the input code out of the loop:

```
int number = FirstScan.nextInt();
int chopperCrash = number;

while (true) {
```

Since you never assign `chopperCrash` inside the loop, it goes on forever. So, put it inside like so:

```
while (true) {
    int number = FirstScan.nextInt();
    int chopperCrash = number;
```